# What is the name of this ymmetric matrix?

Tags: matrices

The following matrix is the covariance matrix of four random variables from a stationary process and with equal intervals between them

\begin{matrix} a & b & c & d \\ b & a & b & c \\ c & b & a & b \\ d & c & b & a\\ \end{matrix}

What is the name of this special matrix? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be a symmetric [Toeplitz matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix).